# Cannot export array bands in Google Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine

I'm new to Google Earth Engine and Google AI Platform. A model was previously trained and published to AI platform and be imported to Earth Engine for image classification. The trained model successfully classified landcover in the specified area into 5 classes, however, I faced some problems when I was trying to export the classified images to my Google Drive.

Below is the script I have so far.
An error message of 'Cannot export array bands' jumped out when I tried to export the result.

How can I export the labeled image and the probability maps?

```
var model_1985 = ee.Model.fromAiPlatformPredictor({
  projectId : 'most-308413',
  modelName : 'Mostcnn_1985',
  version : 'v0',
  inputTileSize : [100, 100],
  proj : ee.Projection('EPSG:4326').atScale(30),
  fixInputProj : true,
  outputBands : {'landclass': {
  'type': ee.PixelType.float(),
  'dimensions': 1}
}
});

var predictions_1985 = model_1985.predictImage(array_image_1985);
var label_1985 = predictions_1985.arrayArgmax().arrayGet([0]).rename('label');
var probabilities_1985 = predictions_1985.arrayFlatten([["builtup","barren","cultivated","water","vegetation"]]);

Export.image.toDrive({
  image: predictions_1985,
  description: 'dl_classified_1985',
  folder: 'GEE',
  region: Clip_Extent,
  scale:20,
  crs: 'EPSG:4326',
})
```

Comment: I have no idea what that error means. However Have You checked whether Your prediction works? You can try to examine Your classification via ´print(probabilities_1985)´. The code is not executed strictly linearly in the Google Earth Engine. There might even be a problem creating the image....

Answer (score 0):

You've done the hard work but looks like you are trying to export the wrong object - you should set `image: probabilities_1985`  in the `Export.image.toDrive command` (rather than `image: predictions_1985`)

I had also been tripped up by this - each pixel of the image returned by `predictImage` is a 1D array rather than a scalar value, so you have to unpack each value into a separate band using `arrayFlatten`, even if your prediction only returns a single value