# Extract data for aoi from preprocessed Landsat CCDC ImageCollection using GEE Python API

Tags: python, google-earth-engine, clip, landsat, xarray

I try to extract for a collection of 1 ha square polygons the bands coefficients from a preprocessed Landsat CCDC Google Earth Engine Asset `ee.ImageCollection('projects/CCDC/v3')`.

My **plan** is the following:

1. Try for a given `ee.Geometry.Point()` location: **OK**.
2. Try for a 1 ha square polygon using `ee.Image.sampleRectangle()`: **FAIL**, returns the same results as for the point Geometry while the aoi contains several pixels (asset resolution = 30 m).
3. Loop through the `ee.FeatureCollection()`: **need input** on an efficient way to iterate. I was thinking of using `map()` and then concatenate/merge the results into an xarray.

**Notes**:

- I am aware of the [gee-ccdc-tools](https://gee-ccdc-tools.readthedocs.io) package, but I am looking for a Python solution.
- I wonder if this could be a projection issue as hinted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64012752/gee-samplerectangle-returning-1x1-array).

```py
import ee
import geemap
import numpy as np

ee.Initialize()

poi = ee.Geometry.Point(-53.423000,-13.623000) # Point of interest
aoi = poi.buffer(50).bounds() # 1 ha rectangle centered on poi

ccdc = ee.ImageCollection('projects/CCDC/v3') # Load asset
ccdc_mosaic = ccdc.mosaic() # Create mosaic from 990 non-overlapping images covering the world

Map = geemap.Map()
Map.addLayer(ccdc_mosaic, {'bands':'GREEN_magnitude', 'min': 0, 'max': 0.01}, 'ccdc_mosaic')
Map.addLayer(poi, {'color': 'red'}, 'poi')
Map.addLayer(aoi, {'color': 'blue'}, 'aoi')
Map.centerObject(aoi)
Map # Display for inspection with 'Inspector'

tEnd_poi = np.array(ccdc_mosaic.sampleRectangle(poi).get('tEnd').getInfo())
tEnd_poi

# This pixel contains 4 time segments: OK
array([[[1999.78662184, 2007.64972982, 2013.694921  , 2019.67435735]]])


GREEN_coefs_poi = np.array(ccdc_mosaic.sampleRectangle(poi).get('GREEN_coefs').getInfo())
GREEN_coefs_poi

# The 8 coefficients for the GREEN band for the 4 time segments: OK
array([[[[ 2.31620175e+01, -1.15526059e-02,  2.27645180e-02,
           0.00000000e+00,  0.00000000e+00,  0.00000000e+00,
           0.00000000e+00,  0.00000000e+00],
         [ 3.99429518e-02,  0.00000000e+00,  1.79411590e-03,
          -1.11117008e-03,  0.00000000e+00,  0.00000000e+00,
           0.00000000e+00,  0.00000000e+00],
         [ 1.17203301e-01, -3.64512731e-05,  4.46052439e-03,
          -1.55708945e-03,  0.00000000e+00,  0.00000000e+00,
           0.00000000e+00,  0.00000000e+00],
         [ 4.13283961e-02,  0.00000000e+00,  2.13285985e-03,
           0.00000000e+00, -1.16010972e-03,  0.00000000e+00,
           0.00000000e+00,  0.00000000e+00]]]])

# Get coefficients for the area of interest
GREEN_coefs_aoi = np.array(ccdc_mosaic.sampleRectangle(aoi).get('GREEN_coefs').getInfo())

GREEN_coefs_poi == GREEN_coefs_aoi
# True...
```

Comment: you should not use sampleRectangle but export the image either as an asset or a .Tif. be aware that if you export to tif you will have an issue as exported bands cannot be arrays. you can have a look here: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/393671/cannot-export-array-bands-in-google-earth-engine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can turn the CCDC segments array image into an image with a band per array element, then use `getDownloadURL()` to extract the data. You will end up with a lot of bands, and you cannot download more than `32MB`. The below script of `1000x1000m` and `6` segments gives you `250` bands and a `17MB` download.

Have a look at Noel's [article](https://gorelick.medium.com/fast-er-downloads-a2abd512aa26) for some more tips on downloads.

```
import ee

ee.Authenticate() # Skip if you're running this in SEPAL
ee.Initialize()


def flattenSegments(segments):
    maxSegments = (segments
        .select('tStart')
        .arrayLength(0)
        .reduceRegion(
            reducer=ee.Reducer.max(),
            geometry=geometry,
            scale=30,
            maxPixels=1e9
        ).getNumber('tStart'))

    return ee.Image(
        ee.List.sequence(0, maxSegments.subtract(1))
        .iterate(
            lambda segmentIndex, acc:
                ee.Image(acc).addBands(toSegment(segmentIndex, segments)),
            ee.Image().select([])
        )
    )


def toSegment(segmentIndex, segments):
    segmentIndex = ee.Number(segmentIndex).int8()
    segment = segments.arraySlice(0, segmentIndex, segmentIndex.add(1))
    coefs = ee.Image(
        ee.List.sequence(0, 7)
        .iterate(
            lambda coefIndex, acc:
                ee.Image(acc).addBands(toCoef(coefIndex, segment)),
            ee.Image().select([])
        )
    )
    otherBands = (segment
        .select(
            segment
            .bandNames()
            .filter(
                ee.Filter.stringEndsWith('item', '_coefs').Not()
            )
        )
        .updateMask(coefs.select(0).mask())
        .arrayGet([0]))
    return (otherBands
        .addBands(coefs)
        .regexpRename('(.*)', segmentIndex.format('%d').cat('_$1'), False))


def toCoef(coefIndex, segment):
    coefIndex = ee.Number(coefIndex).int8()
    coef = (segment
        .select('.*_coefs')
        .arraySlice(1, coefIndex, coefIndex.add(1))
        .regexpRename(
            '(.*)_coefs',
            ee.String('$1_coef_').cat(coefIndex.format('%d'))
        ))
    return (coef
        .updateMask(coef.select(0).arrayLength(0))
        .arrayGet([0, 0]))


geometry = (ee.Geometry.Point([-64.44248584974648, -7.473629193079254])
    .buffer(1000).bounds())

segments = (ee.ImageCollection('projects/CCDC/v3')
    .filterBounds(geometry)
    .mosaic())

flattened = flattenSegments(segments)
url = flattened.getDownloadURL({
    'format': "NPY",
    'region':  geometry
})
```