# How to download a image array in Google Earth Engine?

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-javascript-api, array

I'm trying to export an image array produced by the `ee.Algorithms.TemporalSegmentation.Ccdc` algorithm. This is a 1D image array. I'm trying to export it using:

```
Export.image.toDrive({
  image:ccdc_tBreak,
  description: 'image_export',
  region: geometry,
  scale: 10,
  crs:'EPSG:4326'
});
```

But I obtain the following error:

**Error: Cannot export array bands. (Error code: 3)**

How can I download the image array or, preferably, convert the 1D image array to a `ee.Image()` object to download it without problems?

Here my full script: https://code.earthengine.google.com/e876bf7fa95fecc8a5c69488b8849b0c

Comment: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/393671/cannot-export-array-bands-in-google-earth-engine

Answer (score 1):

I was able to convert the 1D image array into an `ee.Image()` object using `ee.Image.arrayFlatten()` as follows:

```
var ccdc_tBreak = ccdc.select('tBreak').arrayFlatten([['tBreat']]);
```