# GEE Cannot export array bands. (Error code: 3)

Tags: google-earth-engine

I'm trying to export an image array produced by the ee.Algorithms.TemporalSegmentation.Ccdc algorithm. This is a 1D image array. I'm trying to export it using:

```
Export.image.toDrive({
  image: ccdc_tBreak,
  description: 'firstImage',
  crs: "EPSG:4326",
  scale: 30,
  region: Area,
  maxPixels: 1e13,
});
```

But I obtain the following error:

> Error: Cannot export array bands. (Error code: 3)

How can I download the image array or, preferably, convert the 1D image array to a ee.Image() object to download it without problems?

Here my full script: https://code.earthengine.google.com/0d109f15f844c8499bf14c8fdb26b226

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `tBreak` band is an array image -- each pixel has one or more values (the length of the array is variable). You could [get the first value of each array](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/apidocs/ee-image-arrayget) and export this as an image, or you can use [ee.Image.arrayReduce](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/apidocs/ee-image-arrayreduce) to reduce the array to a single value in each pixel. Here's a demonstration using the first value only. I would recommend going through the documentation of the other **ee.Image.array*** functions.

```js
var ccdc_img = ee.ImageCollection("GOOGLE/GLOBAL_CCDC/V1")  
  .select('tBreak')
  .filterBounds(Area)
  .first() 
  .clip(Area)
Map.addLayer(ccdc_img, {min:2010, max:2019}, "First image as array.")

var ccdc_img_reduced = ccdc_img.arrayGet([0]) 
//https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/apidocs/ee-image-arrayget

Map.addLayer(ccdc_img_reduced, {min:2010, max:2019}, "First image -- first value only")

Export.image.toDrive({
  image: ccdc_img_reduced,
  description: 'firstimage-export-first-value',
  crs: "EPSG:4326",
  scale: 30,
  region: Area,
  maxPixels: 1e13,
});
```

https://code.earthengine.google.com/246710700db5706950f1eff48e50e8c4

See also:

[Cannot export array bands in Google Earth Engine](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/393671/cannot-export-array-bands-in-google-earth-engine?rq=1)